# List python directory and subdirectories in alphabetical order

Tags: python, sorting, directory

I am new to python and am trying to list my files in alphabetical order

For a sample file it should print what you see here:

```
>>> print_dir_contents (’sample’)
Contents of directory sample
4 files:
  file_1.txt
  file_2.txt
  file_3.txt
  file_4.txt
2 subdirectories:
  dir_1
dir_2
```

I'm sure this can be done.

I have written broad code for printing the name of the directory file but this is not specific enough:

```
 import os

 def print_dir_contents (string):
   for name in os.listdir (string):
    path = os.path.join (string, name)
if os.path.isfile(path):
   print (path)
else:
    print_dir_contents (path)
```

I am guessing the sort () will be used for alphabetical order. And I'm guessing this should be fairly quick. Can anybody help?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting ... how did your research *not* find a reasonable introduction to sorting?

Comment: Recreational user who hasn't researched for long. Thought I'd ask here

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
In the meantime, the link I posted should get you there.  In short, you put all your file names into a list, and then sort the list (no further arguments).

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
def print_dir_contents (string):
    Dir=[]
    File=[]
    print("Contents of directory {}".format(string))
    if not os.path.exists(string):
        print("Directory not found")
        return
    for name in os.listdir(string): 
        path= os.path.join (string, name)   
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            File.append(name)
        else:
            Dir.append(name)
    print("{} files".format(len(File)))
    for x in sorted(File):
        print('-->'+x)
    print("{} subdirectories".format(len(Dir)))
    for x in sorted(Dir):
        print('-->'+x)

print_dir_contents('Sample')
```